# Bayesian Logistic Regression with Regularization

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, bayesian, regularization

For one of my Statistics for Analytics semester projects, I am thinking of applying concepts of Bayesian Statistics, Regression and Regularization in R.

1. I can easily find resources on Bayesian Logistic Regression and Logistic Regression with Regularization but I am unable to find something that involves all three of these. I do get something like "Bayesian Regularization" but I think it is something different than what I am looking for (not sure it makes sense or sounds dumb since I am not an expert and will be learning these concepts before working on the project).
2. Also, for reducing variables, does it make more sense to use PCA or Exploratory Factor Analysis, given that my project requirement is that results should be "interpretable"?

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me out and give some suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The priors for a Bayesian model induce a sort of regularization.  This is best seen in linear regression, where the is a 1:1 correspondence between model prior standard deviations and the penalty parameter in something like lasso and ridge regression.  Another interpretation would be to use Laplace priors for the coefficients of your Bayesian model, thereby making a sparsity assumption.  This may or may not be easy.  I'm not sure if libraries like `brms` implement such priors.  Michael Betancourt has written on the topic of Bayes sparse regression, so if you are able to understand [this](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/bayes_sparse_regression.html), then I think this is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please comment on the 2nd part as well? Does it make sense to use EFA/PCA prior to logistic regression? Will it be redundant because using regularization to force some coefficients might also help me reduce the number of predictor variables?

Comment: @ShahzebNaveed One reason to use Bayes is that we can get meaningful probability estimates from our model.  If you do PCA or similar techniques, you lose interpretability.  You could do it if you wanted, but I just don't see why you would want to do a Bayesian analysis if you did.

Answer (score 1):

There are several shrinkage priors in the Bayesian context. For instance, the Horseshoe prior, the LASSO prior, and some others. See

[Hierarchical Shrinkage Priors for Regression Models](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1453211963)

For an implementation in STAN, see for instance:

https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/bayesian-logistic-regression-with-horseshoe-prior/7484

Another option is to use the Polya-Gamma sampler from:

[Bayesian Inference for Logistic Models Using Pólya–Gamma Latent Variables](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2013.829001)

This can be coupled with several shrinkage priors using another hierarchical level (as explained in the paper).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please comment on the 2nd part as well? Does it make sense to use EFA/PCA prior to logistic regression? Will it be redundant because using regularization to force some coefficients might also help me reduce the number of predictor variables?